# In window,numeric up down control ,how can i make increment for half an hour

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I would like to ask how to make  time interval(half and hour) increase or decrease ,when I click Up /down button in numeric up down control.

Answer (score 2):

NumericUpDown control doesn't support for time. However, if you want to use its value as number of minutes you can set its [Increment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.increment(v=vs.110).aspx) property to 30.

[NumericUpDown.Increment Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.increment(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets or sets the value to increment or decrement the spin box (also
>   known as an up-down control) when the up or down buttons are clicked.
>
> Clicking the up button causes the Value property to increment by the
>   amount specified by the Increment property and approach the Maximum
>   property. Clicking the down button causes the Value property to be
>   decremented by the amount specified by the Increment property and
>   approach the Minimum property.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a NumericUpDown that will only allow you to have whole and half values:

```
public class HalfHourNumericUpDown : NumericUpDown
{

    public HalfHourNumericUpDown()
    {
        this.DecimalPlaces = 1;
    }

    public override void UpButton()
    {
        if (this.Value <= this.Maximum - (decimal).5)
            this.Value = this.Value + (decimal).5;
        else
            this.Value = this.Maximum;
        this.RoundToHalf();
    }

    public override void DownButton()
    {
        if (this.Value >= (decimal).5)
            this.Value = this.Value - (decimal).5;
        else
            this.Value = this.Minimum;
        this.RoundToHalf();
    }

    protected override void UpdateEditText()
    {
        base.UpdateEditText();
        this.RoundToHalf();
    }

    private void RoundToHalf()
    {
        decimal value = this.Value;
        value = value * 2;
        value = Math.Round(value, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        value = value / (decimal)2;
        this.Value = Math.Min(this.Maximum, Math.Max(value, this.Minimum));
    }

}
```